# How to merge changes into a Git repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I made a mistake when copying our repo to the dev directory. After running `mkdir dev && cd dev && git clone <projecturl>` I decided to copy the files out of the clone `dev/myproject` directory into the parent directory `dev`. The problem is I forgot to copy over `.git`, so now all of my changes exist in a directory that isn't a Git repo, and I have no obvious way to commit the changes that I'm aware of.

I tried this and it did not work:

```
cp -RfHip production/.git dev/.git
```

I'm wondering how I can merge my changes without creating merge conflicts, if possible. My changes are significant enough that having to manually merge them is not feasible. I guess if all else fails I could just copy the files from dev to production and then commit it, and start removing the old files from production that don't get overwritten in the commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So funny thing, i was able to solve it myself. `cp` is unable to copy subdirectories. i needed to `cd` to the `production` directory and copy the files from there.

`cd production && cp -rfHip .git ../dev/.git && cd ../dev && git add -A && git commit -a`